# C# and MongoDb find geo

Tags: c#, .net, nosql

I trying to find locations from MondoDb.
I have MongoDb collection 'Station' with format

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5809bd6b0d2e2437b0a745af"),
"Price" : "1.0",
"IsBusy" : false,
"StationType" : 1772,
"Image" : "123",
"Location" : {
    "Type" : "Point",
    "Coordinates" : [ 
        53.9230359, 
        27.5110339
    ]
}
```

}

Insert document to collection

```
Db.GetCollection<Station>("Stations").Indexes.CreateOne("{'Location': '2dsphere'}");
await Db.GetCollection<Station>("Stations").InsertOneAsync(station);
```

I send the same coordinates which I used to document earlier and then I try to get locations

```
var gp = new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(longtitude, latitude));
var query = Builders<Station>.Filter.Near("location", gp, distance);
var result = await Db.GetCollection<Station>("Stations").Find(query).ToListAsync();
```

I tried this code but result the same

```
var point = new GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates(longtitude, latitude);
var pnt=new GeoJsonPoint<GeoJson2DGeographicCoordinates>(point);
var dis = distance*1609.34;
var fil = Builders<Station>.Filter.Near(p => p.Location, pnt, dis);
var result = await Db.GetCollection<Station>("Stations").Find(fil).ToListAsync();
```

I don't get any result and error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a decision.
The coordinates must be stored in the longitude, latitude order.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5809d5598056df4c10c8af49"),
"Price" : "1.0",
"IsBusy" : false,
"StationType" : 1772,
"Image" : "123",
"location" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [ 
        27.5110339, 
        53.9230359
    ]
}
```

}